# Printing a list with elements depending on size of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers and I want to print a list containing, for example, k number of elements in the list depending on the "k" value.

For example, if k = 4, this means that the list I will be printing will have exactly 4 elements in the list. For k = 5, 5 elements in the list, etc.

Here's my code:

```
listA = [9,-2,6,1,80,9,-2]

def findMinimum(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]

    else:
        minNumber = findMinimum(l[1:])
        minimumVal = l[0]
        if minNumber<minimumVal:
            minimumVal = minNumber
        return minimumVal

def listMin(k,l):
    temp = []*k
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        minVal = findMinimum(l)
        temp.append(minVal)

        for item in temp:
           if item in l:
              l.remove(item)
    print(temp)

listMin(4,listA)
```

The **first function** defined finds the **minimum value** in the list and returns the minimum value.

The **second function** has 2 parameters which are the k value and list. The **k value is the size of the list to return** which I'm having issues on. Whenever a minimum value is obtained and appended into the temp list, it **removes** it from **list A** and will then proceed on to obtain the next minimum digit in the list `A`.

An example of output will be when k = 4, hence the list will have four elements in it:

```
[-2,-2,1,6]
```

The code I wrote gave me 6 elements in the list instead of 4:

```
[-2,-2,1,6,9,9]
```

I'm guessing my mistake would be temp = []*k.

Comment: So, you want the *k* smallest elements?

Comment: Hint: What is `k * 0`? What then is `k * []`? But that's not the problem, since you are `append`ing to the list anyway, so you don't have to initialize with any specific size.

Comment: Why just not sort and slice it? `lowest_four = sorted(listA)[:4]`

Comment: @zwer This is so needlessly complex that I'm assuming it's an assignment to teach recursion.

Comment: Your loop is wrong. Use `for i in range(k):` then it "works".

Comment: @Nuageux yes, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Also, your function is modifying the list, which is probably not intentional.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein correct, recursion method. Not an assignment but a practice question

Comment: @tobias_k thanks a bunch. silly mistake

Comment: @Electric So, an assignment where you're the one assigning it to yourself.  :-)  Either way, it's all good.  If I may suggest for the future, though, be up front about your design - state in the question that you're deliberately using recursion (whether for an assignment or for practice doesn't matter - the community generally looks to see that you understand enough of what you're doing to be helped, and your code did show that).  This will save people answering from giving irrelevant answers, as 2 of the current 3 answers right now are.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein understood, somehow I'm callous when writing questions. I'll improve on it as much as possible. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
```

should be changed to:

```
for i in range(k):
```

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First. You don't need to hand-write function to find minimum in python. There's built-in [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)
Second. If you expect your program to operate on multiple values inside datastructure, in most cases operating "all at once" is a good idea.
According to your code:

- sort list ascending (with built-in [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)
- [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) the list up to `k` values

So, you can end up with

```
sorted(listA)[:k]
```

To achieve same result by "one-by-one" operations you can

- find minimum
- remove single element by value
- add it to new list
- do it `k` times

Which can look like

```
result = []
for _ in range(k):
    value = min(ListA)
    listA.remove(value)
    result.append(value)
```

Comment: interesting! But I'm not sure if I'm permitted to do so in exams. Maybe I'll get to know these in the higher level.

Answer (score 0):

You made the problem much more complex than it should be:

```
l = [9,-2,6,1,80,9,-2]

k = 4

n = []

while k > 0:
    m = min(l)
    n.append(m)
    l.remove(m)
    k -= 1

print n

>> [-2, -2, 1, 6]
```

Comment: I've opted for the longer method. I didn't mention it but its a must. Sorry for the misunderstanding.